# execute similar files in different directories python

Tags: python

I about 100 files each stored in a different directory. I have written a script but currently I am running this script for all of these files one at a time. I know if I save these files in one directory I can run them all one after the other using os.chdir, os.listdir. 
But for me moving them to one directory is not an option.
Is there a way to execute all these files consecutively in a order and make my life easier?

Comment: Do you really mean "execute" or rather "process"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generally use `os.walk` for this kind of thing:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath("/parent/dir/")):
  for file in files:
    if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.py':
      print os.path.join(root, file)
```

Also works nicely with `fnmatch`:

```
import os
import fnmatch

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/parent/dir/"):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.py'):
    # do your thing here .. execfile(filename) or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused.  If you want to do this all from within python by changing the current directory (presumably because your functions use relative paths):

```
directory_list = [ ... ] #list of directories.  You could possibly get it from glob.glob
here = os.getcwd() #remember the "root" directory
for directory in directory_list:
    os.chdir(directory) #change to the "work" directory

    #do work in "work" directory

    os.chdir(here) #go back to the root directory
```

Of course, if you already have the script cloned into your 100 directories, then you can just run it via bash:

```
for DIR in directory_glob_pattern; do cd $DIR && python runscript.py && cd -; done
```